# Wierd Delphi behavour

Tags: delphi

Due to a bug in my code I stumbled upon this scenario by accident: -

```
function Bogus: string;
begin
end;

var
  s: string;
begin
  s:='Original value';
  s:=Bogus;
  MessageDlg(s, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end.
```

Will show a dialog of `Original value` where the non-result of my function call has no effect on my var; I would have expected it to be empty.

Is this the expected behaviour?  Can it be relied upon?  Would anyone actually implement this on purpose??!?

<sub>I've been using Delphi since 1995 and have never encountered this before.

(Even to this day I still won't select text from the cursor placed by the IDE on a compile error as that used to crash Delphi 1.0!!!)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the `string` return value of `Bogus()` is passed using a hidden `var` parameter (not an `out` parameter, like you are thinking of), *as if* you had written your code like this instead:

```pascal
procedure Bogus(var Result: string);
begin
end;

var
  s: string;
begin
  s:='Original value';
  Bogus(s);
  MessageDlg(s, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end.
```

Since `Bogus()` does not assign anything to its `Result`, the original `string` value is preserved (*undefined behavior*), which is why you are able to see it in the `MessageDlg()` afterwards.

However, this is a widely known *implementation detail* that you should NOT rely on.  You should *always* assign *something* to the `Result` of a `function`.  The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Function_Declarations) merely says:

> If the function exits without assigning a value to `Result` or the function name, then **the function's return value is undefined**.

Comment: Aha, thanks so much for that. I did search for an answer first but didn't think of the correct words to search for obviously! The only concern I had was that it didn't yield a compiler hint / warning (at least in Delphi 6.0 - I didn't try all my compilers!).  Thanks for your quick and clear answer :)